# how to prevent warnings from displaying to anonymous users

Tags: 7, status-messages

As in subject: how to prevent warnings from displaying to anonymous users? They contain paths etc. Even better, how to display warnings only to priviledged users?

Comment: Do you really want to prevent *all* warnings from displaying to anonymous users? remember that this includes important error messages like "incorrect password" for users that are currently anonymous but trying to log in...

Comment: Of course, not. The messages that are specifically for end users should still be shown. But I don't know how to differentiate them automatically (I'll check the module disable_messages mentioned below). And in any case, messages that contain paths and system errors should NOT be displayed to anonymous users.

Comment: Sure, in D6 I used http://drupal.org/project/messages_alter which provides a hook and a php class for matching/editing messages. Hasn't been ported to D7 yet so I can't really add this as an answer >.<

Comment: Feature request here https://www.drupal.org/node/2743119

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you should turn down the error_reporting options on your production server. This will erase most of PHP's warnings and notifications.

Also you can configure drupal to only log the errors. To do that go to `Administration > Configuration > Development > Logging and errors` or directly to the path `/admin/config/development/logging` and set "Error messages to display" to none. Drupal then still logs errors but doesn't display them to users.

If you still need finer control over messages surely the module [disable_messages](http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages) can help you.

Comment: If I set error_reporting e.g. to 0, will the errors still be visible in watchdog? The point is to hide them from users, but leave a trace of what happened to admins.